# How to remove blue shadow on textbutton when it's pressed (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I'd like to remove the shadow that appears when you press a text button on Flutter,  I've looked everywhere and can't find an answer !
Help me please !
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You should check the documentation of `TextButton` and especially the `style` [ButtonStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html). You need to change the `overlayColor` as per documentation:

> The highlight color that's typically used to indicate that the button is focused, hovered, or pressed.

Comment: If you want this to persist for all buttons, add the buttonStyle to your app's ThemeData.

Answer (score 1):

In a newer Flutter versions use

```
style: TextButton.styleFrom(
  splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using TextButton, I recommend you to use Text Widget using GestureDetector. So the Text is there is no shadow color.

Example:

```
GestureDetector(
    child: Text('Click me'),
    onTap: () {},
)
```

Comment: I'll try this, thank youu !